# Circular import in python+django?! how to make it work?

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm spliting my files because the model is getting bigger. So here we are again with problems:

My models;
If in my Category model I remove the "ArticleToCategory" and the many-to-many relationship it works well. But I need them!

How to fix it?

I deleted the model.py in order to load files from the model package.

Category (models.category):

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    # relationships
    from RubeteDjango01.generic.models.article import Article
    from RubeteDjango01.generic.models.article_to_category import ArticleToCategory
    articles = m.ManyToManyField(Article, through=ArticleToCategory)
```

ArticleToCategory (models.article_to_category):

```
from django.db import models as m

class ArticleToCategory(m.Model):
    from RubeteDjango01.generic.models.article import Article
    from RubeteDjango01.generic.models.category import Category

    article = m.ForeignKey(Article)
    category = m.ForeignKey(Category)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'articles_to_categories'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ArticlesToCategories'
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define foreign keys using strings, to avoid exactly this problem.

```
class Art2C(..):
    art = m.ForeignKey('Article')
    from_other_app = m.ForeignKey('other_app.Article')
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I was trying to put the absolute path of the module with dot notation, but it was not working. Thanks again ;) you saved me a lot of time ;) ps.: I liked that you showed how to import a model from another app too. that is really great to know. :D

Comment: I have to ask you another thing: in which other places I might use this notation? post_save... and things like this.?

Comment: pretty much everywhere else you can just move the import statement into the function call to avoid circular import problems

Comment: I also had success using `importlib.import_module`.